# SSRS pagination options (KeepTogether, KeepWithGroup) not affecting printable output formats (PDF)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, pagination, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report with a pretty simple overall structure, and I am trying to use the KeepTogether, KeepWithGroup, and RepeatOnNewPage properties of tablix members to control how groupings display on multiple pages.

Everything works beautifully in the web mode of the report, but printable formats like PDF and Word completely ignore these settings. They instead to appear to treat the report as one giant long page, and then insert their own pagination wherever they need to.

Here is what the tablix looks like:

[image: Tablix]

And here are the row groupings (in advanced mode), with annotations for the properties I have set for them:

[image: Grouping]

This is all on SQL Server 2012 SP 1 CU 16 (recognizing that there was presumably a bugfix for KeepTogether in CU1). What's the deal here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to review your Column Groups as well I think (the logic is backwards I feel). Looks like you found the `Advanced` section in the grouping pane. The rows are on the left and columns on the right - try setting the keep together properties for the static column grouping items as well.

Comment: Look at the tablix again. There’s only one column—no groups. The columns in the second detail row are a sub-tablix.

Comment: can you configure the static column groupings on your sub-tablix?

Comment: The sub tablix is just static columns in a static row—no groupings at all.

Comment: Ok yeah. Nested tablicies and keep together are not friends.

Comment: I removed the row with the nested tablix and am still seeing the problem in PDF format. Everything is still working as expected in the HTML format.